# Modifying the PATH environment variable for the session

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

I am trying to write a windows 10 batch file to modify the PATH variable for the current session only. I do the following:

```
SET PATH = "d:\A\B\C\D\E\";%PATH%
echo %PATH%
```

The echo of the path shows that the path variable is unchanged. How do I change the variable?

Thanks

Comment: You only need the double quotes if you're adding a path with an embedded space. Other than that, this should work fine.

Comment: Look into the `path` command.  In a console window, `path /?` for details.  I think what you're looking for is `path D:\A\B\C\D\E;%PATH%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check `echo %path %` - and then remove the spaces around the `=` in your `set` command. Those spaces are part of your variable name respective your value.